# direction of magnetic field through circular circuit

Tags: electromagnetism

If current passes through the circular circuit in anti-clockwise direction,in center of the wire a North pole is generated. WHY?
      Please, answer me SIR with required diagram so that I can understand easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the magnetic field pattern due to a loop of wire you will see that magnetic field lines are coming out of the right hand side of the loop which is what you would expect to happen if a north pole of a magnet was in that position.
It is not really a north pole rather it behaves like a north pole.

[image]

Looking from the other side of the loop the magnetic field lines are going into the loop just like the south pole of a magnet.